# How to get values from dictionary for only one part of key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like that:

```
d = {
    (1, 'first'): [1],
    (1, 'second'): [2],
    (1, 'first'): [3],
    (2, 'second'): [4],
    (2, 'first'): [5],
    (2, 'second'): [6]
}
```

I would like to get only the values with the key containing `second`, so I would get only:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Is there a easy way of doing it, something like `.loc` in pandas?

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this? Do you know that you can use `[v for k, v in d.items() if 'second' in k]` to get `[[2], [4], [6]]`? Is your problem how to convert this to `[2, 4, 6]`? (assuming that the keys were actually unique...)

Comment: Where does the `4` come from. The key `(2, 'second')` is duplicate, so there is no `4` in this dictionary.

Comment: Feel free to vote up any answers that work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple function like the following:

```
def keyContains(d, expr):
    res = []
    for k in d.keys():
        if expr == k[1]:
            res.extend(d[k])
    return res
```

PS: Two of the keys in your example are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
numbers = [value[0] for key, value in d.items() if key[1] == 'second']
print(numbers)
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 6]
```

Items with values 4 and 6 have the same key. And the same goes for 1 and 3. Hence, when d gets instantiated and the interpreter iterates through the lines, the end result only contains:

```
{
    (1, 'first'): [3],
    (1, 'second'): [2],
    (2, 'first'): [5],
    (2, 'second'): [6]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate keys in your dict, so it might not give correct result. Change the keys of your dict such that all keys are unique. After that, use loop to find them. Seperate the keys and values using `.items()`. Keys will be of type tuples. Using if statement, check if the second element of the tuple is "second". If yes, collect the value in a list and finally print it. Your code:

```
d = {
    (1, 'first'): [1],
    (1, 'second'): [2],
    (3, 'first'): [3],
    (2, 'second'): [4],
    (2, 'first'): [5],
    (3, 'second'): [6]
}          #unique keys
l=[]
for key,value in d.items():
    if key[1]=="second":
        l.append(*value)
        
print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll show you how to do this with pure python and with pandas, but i prefer the pure python way

Code:

```py
# pure python way:

myDict = {
    (1, 'first'): [1],
    (1, 'second'): [2],
    (1, 'first'): [3],
    (2, 'second'): [4],
    (2, 'first'): [5],
    (2, 'second'): [6]
}

myList = []

for key in myDict.keys():
    if key[1] == 'second':
        myList.append(myDict[key][0])

print(myList)

# output:
[2, 6]

# pandas way:

myDict = {
    (1, 'first'): [1],
    (1, 'second'): [2],
    (1, 'first'): [3],
    (2, 'second'): [4],
    (2, 'first'): [5],
    (2, 'second'): [6]
}

myList = []

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict)

for column in df:
    if column[1] == 'second'
        myList.append(df[column].values[0])

print(myList)

# output:
[2, 6]
```

Comment: So the Pandas way is identical to the pure Python way except that a DataFrame needs to be constructed first? That seems a bit pointless. I'm sure Pandas has better ways to do this.

Comment: i expressed myself poorly before. The pure python way is easier in my opinion but the pandas way is faster than pure python way because pandas library was developed in lower level languages, so the pandas way is more efficient.

Comment: It's only more efficient when using methods that operate on whole columns or dataframes at once, there is no advantage when accessing each element individually in a `for` loop.